# libreoffice Text Aggregator

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

Is it possible to concatenate text from an aggregate function in LibreOffice Base.  For example:

| column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 23 |
| 2 | World | 27 |

The function would then return "Hello, world"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which database you are using.

Please look at the statusbar at the bottom left. If you see something like this, then the built-in Firebird database is being used.

[image: FireBird]

In this case, you can use the [**LIST() aggregate function**](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/nullguide-aggrfunc.html#:%7E:text=Comma%2Dseparated%20string%20concatenation%20of%20non%2DNULL%20values%20in%20the%20column). Something similar to

`SELECT LIST("Column2") AS string_agg FROM "MyTable"`

If you have created an HSQLDB database, you can try to tame the [**GROUP_CONCAT() function**](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#:%7E:text=with%20this%20function.-,GROUP_CONCAT,-is%20a%20specialised)

[image: HSQLDB]

In case you are using a different database, check the documentation for that particular database - there are similar functions in each SQL dialect, but they differ in syntax.